# React.lazy doesn't improve lighthouse or PageSpeed Insights score. Is it a problem actually?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I introduce lazy, dynamic, suspense in React, it works, the concerned elements are loaded at the end.
But my problem is that it doesn't improve at all any score coming from lighthouse or PageSpeed Insights. For me, it was normal that lazy loading would trigger way later than at the end of loading. So is the problem coming from lighthouse etc.. or not ?

Comment: Without a URL or a Lighthouse/PageSpeed Insights report to share, there's not much anyone can do to help debug the issue you're facing. For instance, using `lazy` _could_ help by delaying the load of unimportant components until they're needed, it could hurt by introducing an extra delay if used on components that are needed immediately, or it could have no real impact because the performance bottleneck is somewhere else in the page load. Without being able to see what Lighthouse is saying about the page, it's impossible to tell where the issue lies.

Comment: Sorry for that, here's the site I am working on : amaurypichat.fr